# SIngle master view controller and multiple single view controller using UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, segue, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am new in IOS,

I try to work with UISplitViewController. But Single Master view and single detail view in work properly then add second detail view controller, but it's not work as first detail view controller but it's override on the first detail view controller, i try to it's display on right side of the first detail view controller not override on first detail view controller.

Below I display to to try my code

First prepareForSegue method but it can't work:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Action"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        ViewController *view = (ViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        view.imageName = [_images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        view.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;

    }
}
```

Second didSelectRowAtIndexPath it's work but override first detail view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ViewController *view = (ViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    NSString *imageName = [_images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    view.imageName = imageName;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];

}
```

Thank You.